# Importance of Slepian's Lemma?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, information-theory

[Slepian's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slepian%27s_lemma) states that if one has two Gaussian vectors $\vec X, \vec Y$ such that

1. the means and variances of $\vec X_i, \vec Y_i$ agree for each $i$, and
2. the covariances $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y_iY_j]$,

then

$$\Pr[\cup_i\{X_i>u_i\}]\geq \Pr[\cup_i\{Y_i>u_i\}]$$

One application of this is for tail-bounding Gaussians.
If we want a bound on $\vec Y$ (which may have complicated coordinate-wise dependencies), Slepian's Lemma allows us to replace this with $\vec X$, with no dependencies.

This seems cool, and was how I motivated it to myself when I first came across it.
Upon further thought though, this reasoning doesn't seem great.
The natural way to bound $\Pr[\cup_i \{X_i>u_i\}]$ is via the union bound, which

1. is relatively tight for the suprema of Gaussians, and
2. also doesn't care about dependence between coordinates.

So the previously-described setting does not seem particularly useful for Slepian's lemma.

When is it useful then?

Comment: The most standard application is in showing lower bounds on  $\mathbb{E}[\max_{i \le n} X_i]$ for correlated $X$. You should note that showing that this is $\gtrsim \sqrt{\log n}$ is easy for independent Gaussian vectors, but the standard way to deal with the dependent case is by setting up an appropriate $Y$ for them and hitting this with (some variation of) Slepian's lemma. This is usually called Sudakov minorisation.